# Css position: table and div inside div

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck here with an easy css problem:

The problem is to align "World" text inside the div element at the bottom right.

Here is a fiddle:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/0p6w3x14/2/

```
<div id="container">
<div id="tableElement">
    <table> <!-- this table needs to be here, it's containing more info -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                 Hello
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
    <div id="element">
        World
    </div>

</div>

#container
{
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;  
}

#tableElement
{
border: 1px solid black;
display: inline-block;
}

table
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100px;
}

#element
{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: refer my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your css like this:

```
#container
{
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;  
    position:relative; // add this line
}

#element
{
    display: inline-block;
    position:absolute; //add this line
    bottom:0; //add this line
    right:0; //add this line
   border: 1px solid green;
}
```

and remove `float:right`

**[Working fiddle here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/0p6w3x14/3/)**

Comment: @gr3g Please check/tick the answer to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Lx9gydq1/).

I didn't use

```
float: right
```

and

```
display: inline-block
```

But instead I set a defined width, set its Left property to 100% and then use margin to adapt it to the container

```
#element{
    width: 45px;
    top:100%;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: -45px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be simply done by giving `#element` the styles `position:absolute;`, `bottom:0;` and `right:0`. And then giving `#container` the style `position:relative;` like this:

```
#container
{
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;  
position:relative; // Parent needs relative positioning if child will have absolute positioning
}


#element
{
border: 1px solid green;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
right:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/0p6w3x14/5/)